# Verifying SSL certificate for DDNS domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, ddns

I've a home server set on Raspberry Pi 5 that provide me a bunch of services that are available on my LAN. I've also exposed WireGuard VPN, so I'm able to access my services from outside of my home. I've dynamic IP, so I've been using No-Ip DDNS and it's working just fine. I want to setup nextcloud and want to also expose it, because I don't want my family or friends to use VPN to access it. And here is the point of my question. I want to grab SSL certificate for it. I've started from getting one from ZeroSSL and stuck on verification. Most convenient way is by adding a CNAME record. No-Ip allows me to do that, but also to my domain and no subdomains, which unfortunately is the way it's working in ZeroSSL.
There is also email verification of file verification, but I don't want to expose email server for security reasons and I believe this last file method can also be problematic.
I'm using CasaOS and have Nginx Proxy Manager set on 80. I'm using AdGuard Home as DNS server and I've some internal DNS records created which are proxied to proper port on my server by Nginx Proxy Manager. For example `adguarg.home` is proxied to `192.168.1.100:8081`. I want the rest of my services to be kept internal and only Nextcloud to be exposed. Can I pass the file verification if my 80 port is being proxied to Nextcloud? Is there a better way of verifying my DDNS domain using CNAME records?